# Assigning value of 'this' in JavaScript constructor

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, this

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm currently playing with html5 canvas api. Since I first have to create canvas element, and than get 2d/3d context (which is 2 unconnected variables) it seemed logical to create something that would merge those two into one.

Idea is to have graphics (`gfx`) object (which is actually context object) and `graphics.canvas` which is reference to canvas element so that I can do something like `gfx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);` and maybe re size canvas with `gfx.canvas.width = x;` etc...

When I try to create a constructor function, it doesn't really work out, I have come up with a solution to return `context` object with `canvas` as property but I'm not sure if this is the right way.

**What would be the best approach to this problem?**

Here's my code:

```js
function Canvas (context, width, height) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    contex = canvas.getContext(context);

    this = contex; // <<-- Getting error here
    this.canvas = canvas;

    this.canvas.width = width;
    this.canvas.height = height;

    this.append = function () {
        document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    };
}

function Canvas2 (context, width, height) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    contex = canvas.getContext(context);

    contex.canvas = canvas;

    contex.canvas.width = width;
    contex.canvas.height = height;

    contex.append = function () {
        document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    };

    return contex;
}

var gfx = new Canvas('2d', 400, 400),
gfx2 = Canvas2('2d', 400, 400);

gfx.append();
gfx2.append();
```

Comment: You can't assign `this` to anything. It is read-only.

Comment: You simply cannot change the `this` pointer. That's ecmascript.

Comment: @js1568 That's a useless comment if you don't explain what you mean

Comment: @LeeTaylor I think you said that wrong. You probably meant "You can't assign anything to `this`"

Comment: @Ian A little ambiguous, yes. You can't assign `this` to be something else!

Comment: Thank you, but is the second approach better in this case, or is there something else even more suitable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is a reserved word in JavaScript and refers to the *read-only* context variable.  You cannot reassign it.

If there is no reason you can't simply continue to use the `contex` variable, do that.  If you need to create a local variable, then name it something else:

```
var that = contex;
```

Comment: `contex` is intentionally misspelled. It refers to context object that is retrieved from `canvas.getContext(context)`, while `context` is argument of my constructor and its value is a string `'2d' || '3d'`.

I'm not sure how this creates global variable, can you explain it out a bit more?

Comment: @Jinx Then you need to put `var` before it, unless you want the variable to be global.

Comment: So what is preferred approach to achieve something like this? I mean, is my second solution acceptable or is there some other approach?

Comment: @Jinx I see.  I would suggest indenting the second line of that declaration then, as your nonstandard formatting is confusing.  It's still not clear why you cannot simply use the `contex` variable.  (You probably want to use `contex` instead of `this` inside of the anonymous function, too.)

Answer (score 0):

With ES2015 you could do

```
Object.assign(this, contex)
```